# async.js: iterate a collection until one returns true

Tags: javascript, arrays, async.js

I'm very happy with what async.js can do, but it seems to be missing one thing that I need it to do right now:

I have an array containing data.

```
[{"name": "bob", "age":15},
 {"name": "bill", "age":19},
 {"name": "john", "age": 24}]
```

I want to call the **same** function with **array[i]** as parameter until it returns true for one of the contents of the array. (in this exampe, maybe write users to a database until one of them has at least a specified age, return errors if not).
so:
try bob -> error
then try bill -> success -> then continue with the next task and DON'T go on

everything I've found requires an array of functions (not data) or doesn't seem to know the idea "try until you find one that matches".

Or maybe I didn't read the [docs](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html) well enough?
How can I do this? thanks

Comment: Why would you even use `async` for that? Iterating over an array until some condition is true only requires basic loop logic, hot sure how or why async even enters the picture. Can you post the full code you've tried so far? Or a [mcve]?

Comment: because i want to call a server on every iteration. i noticed that a normal for-loop just continues instead of waiting if the first one was successful. so i thought async might be able to queue the calls and continue with another function on success

Comment: https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#some

Returns true if at least one element in the coll satisfies an async test. If any iteratee call returns true, the main callback is immediately called.

Comment: i'll look into it, thanks!

Comment: Although using it while fetching stuff from server sounds like bad idea, as it will presumably do so in parrallel, and you will still have multiple requests as they will queue faster than they complete. Better to have a single endpoint for the data and just do a normal `some` with predicate on the resultset. Perhaps the next one `someLimit` with a limit of 1 would work, but still not ideal

Comment: there is ```someSeries```, which does exactly what i want :)

Answer (score 1):

Thats quite easy with plain js. Just wrap a recursive iteration inside a promise:

```
var some = new Promise( res => {
  const arr = [{"name": "bob", "age":15}, {"name": "bill", "age":19},{"name": "john", "age": 24}];
  (function next(i){
    if(i>=arr.length) return res(false);
    someasync(arr[i]).then(result => {
      if(result){
        res(true);
      }else{
        next(i+1);
      }
    });
  })(0);
});
```

The same thing in ESnext:

```
async function some( func, params ){
 for(var i = 0; i < params.length; i++){
   if( await func(params[i]) ){
     return true;
   }
 }
 return false;
}

some(a=>a%2==0, [0,1,2,3,4]).then(alert);
```

Comment: mhhh sorry that's not what i call "quite easy". while it may work, it's a lot of overhead i'd like to avoid

Comment: @devman if this is overhead, why do you embed a whole library :/ ??

Comment: overhead as in "character overhead". i'd rather have a library and write 2 lines, than have no library and write 10 lines

Comment: @devman you either write short or beautiful or fast code. You cant have it all. The upper code is maybe not short, but its readable and quite fast i think.